# Application.Quit() won't work - Unity3D unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've little trouble with my simple game.

I'm using this code for menu control:

```
    #pragma strict

var isIZADJI=false;


function OnMouseEnter()
{
renderer.material.color=Color.red;
}


function OnMouseExit()
{
renderer.material.color=Color.white;
}


function OnMouseUp()
{
if(isIZADJI)
{
Application.Quit();

}
else
{
Kontrola_Zivota.ZIVOTI=3;
Application.LoadLevel(1);

}
}
```

When I click "Play Again" it works fine but when I click "Exit" it just load first level.

Any help here?

Comment: isIZADJI is always false

Comment: Where to change it to true? If I change it in OnMouseUp game always restarting even before I start level?

Comment: In unity I just needed to say on what text "isIZADJI" will be true..
Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

I just thought I'd expand on the solution:

I was reading through your code and I see that what you were looking for was a way to identify which button was clicked. I would like to expand on your answer for anyone who want's to know what your solution was. The way to solve this is to create a string variable to check the name of the thing you are clicking (assuming this is GUI Button) and then to change the state of the var isIZADJI based on that eg:

```
// izlaz[croatian] = exit[english]

// First create a string var for the name of button/GUI/object
var nameOfButton : String;

function OnMouseUp()
{

    if(!(nameOfButton == "izlaz"))
    {
    isIZADJI = false;
    }
    else
    {
    isIZDAJI = true;
    }

    // And then now you can add the rest of your code to quit or load a level
    if(isIZADJI)
    {
    Application.Quit();
    }
    else
    {
    Kontrola_Zivota.ZIVOTI=3;
    Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }

}
```

I hope this helps anyone else with this problem.